# recyclerview of base64 images-scroll slow and laggy

Tags: android, optimization, scroll, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view in which I have list of images which I am getting as base64 string from server. Below is the adapter code which I am using and I am converting base64 string into bitmap in asynctask. When I scroll through the list of images scroll is slow and laggy. How can I optimize my code to make it smooth?

```
 public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Message> imagesEncodedList;
        private Context context;

        public ImageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> imagesEncodedList) {
            this.imagesEncodedList = imagesEncodedList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_image_list, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if (imagesEncodedList.get(position).getImage() != null)
            {
                DownloadImageTask downloadImageTask=new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageView);
                downloadImageTask.execute(imagesEncodedList.get(position).getImage());
            }
            else
            {
                DownloadImageTask downloadImageTask=new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageView);
                downloadImageTask.execute(UriToBase64(Uri.parse(imagesEncodedList.get(position).getUri())));
            }

            if(imagesEncodedList.get(position).getPosted())
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenbordercolour);
            else
                holder.item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redbordercolour);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imagesEncodedList.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private ImageView imageView;
            private LinearLayout item;


            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);
                item=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item);
            }
        }

        private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int bitmapWidth, int bitmapHeight) {
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, true);
        }

        private String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }



        private String UriToBase64(Uri uri) {
            Bitmap bm = null;
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("BHUVNESH", "IOException" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Bitmap resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bm, 300, 300);
            return bitmapToBase64(resizedBitmap);
        }

        private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
            ImageView imageView;
            DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView)
            {
               this.imageView=imageView;
            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(urls[0].getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `i am getting as base64 string from server`. No. You don't. You retrieve a Bitmap from the media store and convert it to a base64 string which you offer as parameter to your async task execute method. The asynctask then converses the base64 to a Bitmap. The whole construction does not make sense. Do away with `UriToBase64()` to begin with. `downloadImageTask.execute(UriToBase64(Uri.parse(imagesEncodedList.get(position).getUri())));`. Impossible code.

Comment: @greenapps please ignore that else condition..look at that if condition..

Comment: `imagesEncodedList.get(position).getImage()`. Will return a base64 encoded string. But we cannot see what `.getImage()` is doing. The else condition cannot be ignored as that is the one used during scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Always use picasso/glide library for setting image in your recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Delete DownloadImageTask for two reasons :

1. turning the image to base64 cost too much , later on you will need to turn it to bitmap so that's twice the work .
2. asynctask is no good for that sort of operation .

You should use a library such as

https://github.com/koush/ion or http://square.github.io/picasso

Or something of the sort with three lines of code you will have the image from the server to the imageview and with mass speed.

Enjoy.

Comment: `asynctask is no good for that sort of operation`. Don't agree. Using an AsyncTask is very fine. It's the code in doInBackground which does the work.

Comment: "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask." not for downloading files ...